# Chromium not loading any page after moving User folder

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, chromium

Let me start off by saying that this started happening after I have moved my user folder(C:\Users\MyUser) to another disk.
The process included booting into windows 7 repair, using `robocopy C:\Users\MyUser D:\Users\MyUser /mir /xj /copyall` between the two drives, deleting the old folder on C and creating a junction `mklink C:\Users\MyUser D:\Users\MyUser /j`. I have only moved MY user folder, not the whole 'Users' folder. Ofcourse, the drive letters have been changed accordingly since the Win7 repair cmd sets them differently.

Now here's the problem:

Chromium window:
[image]

Not a single page opens(settings, history, actual webpage), only a dark background and the crash favicon in the tab.
Going to the **Appdata\Local\Chromium\Application** I've found debug.log and this line keeps repeating in:

> [0513/164752.598:ERROR:sandbox_policy_base.cc(379)] Failed to add sandbox rule. error = 2, subsystem = 0, semantics = 1, pattern = 'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Chromium\Application*.pdb'

Running Chromium with the **--no-sandbox** flag works fine, I can open any webpage and the settings but I'd rather not keep running it like that.

I've tried reinstalling Chromium multiple times, but nothing's changed.
Everything else seems to run fine, the favorites and libraries shortcut all point properly to the MyUser folder on the other drive.
I've also modified the permissions on folders so they look exactly as they have before moving the user folder.

Comment: Try with this `chrome.exe  --disable-gpu-compositing --disable-dwm-composition --disable-gpu`. Does it work now? See this [Don't move your Windows user profiles folder to another drive](http://www.zdnet.com/article/dont-move-your-windows-user-profiles-folder-to-another-drive/)

Comment: Nope, still the same. Dark background and a crash favicon if I try to open a page.

Comment: Do not move the whole User folder. Move this folder`"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google"` and then symlinked that.

Comment: I've moved the whole user folder because of mulitple reasons, main one being that there are several folders inside that I want on the other drive, such as the libraries and programs which install to AppData\Local by default, like Chromium does.

Comment: Then move those specific folder and make a batch file to make those symlinks at once. I even do that for BitTorrent and uTorrent.

Comment: I'll keep testing this setup for now until I run into more issues, then I'll follow your advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Alright, my bad.
Seems like old IE kept downloading the 'wrong' version of Chromium from [here](https://chromium.woolyss.com/). It only offered one installer which turned out to be the developer version(60.0.3099.0). 
Updated IE and installed the latest stable version( 58.0.3029.110) and it seems to work properly now.
Can't say if this is a bug in the dev version or this may still cause issues later on, but for now it works.